# trigger('change') is not working on Select

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I have created a select2 dropdown with

```
    <select class="form-control select2"  id="country">
<option value="1">India</option>
<option value="2">Aus</option>
<option value="3">usa</option>
    </select>
```

Now i am selecting selected value via jquery trigger event

```
$('#country').val('1').trigger('change');
```

here, country gets selected with passed value but On this event i also want to trigger change event which is not triggering.

```
$("#country").change(function() {
alert('on country change');
});
```

If i change manually from select2 then the change event fires and it shows the alert but i want to fire the change event automatically when the country value changes from jquery. Any clues?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should `trigger` after `change` function, like this

```js
$("#country").change(function() {
  alert('on country change');
});

$('#country').val('1').trigger('change');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.10/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.10/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>



<select class="form-control select2"  id="country" style="width: 100px;">
    <option value="1">India</option>
    <option value="2">Aus</option>
    <option value="3">usa</option>
  </select>
```

Comment: That was quite silly. I was thinking it will not effect much as i am implementing in document.ready function.

Comment: So this worked for me for my first dropdown of country however when I apply the same to the state it does not remember the dropdown choice, I am loading the states using ajax based on the country id which now gets triggered correctly even after a page reload but the state is not remembered, any idea?